# Wait for time, then DM with bot, with multiple users at once

Tags: discord.py

I have a discord bot I am working on for practice that reminds the users with a dm after a certain amount of time. My issue is that I am using `time.sleep()` to handle the delay. This stops other users from setting up reminders because it is waiting for the previous `time.sleep()` to end. I want to have multiple requests for a reminder happen simultaneously, rather than wait for each request to end before the next one starts. Below is my code. My discord tokens are hosted in a seprate `.env` file.

```
# bot 2

import os
import discord
import time

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN2')

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(
        f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    remind_me = 'You will be reminded '

    if 'remindme!' in message.content.lower():
        if message.content[-1] == 'h' or \
                message.content[-1] == 's' or\
                message.content[-1] == 'm':
            response = remind_me + '\'' + message.content[10:-3] + '\' in' + message.content[-3::]
            await message.channel.send(response)
        else:
            await message.channel.send('I don\'t understand.')

    if message.content[-1] == 'h':
        time.sleep(3600 * int(message.content[-2]))
        await message.author.send('Reminder! \n' + message.content[10:-3])

    if message.content[-1] == 's':
        time.sleep(int(message.content[-2]))
        await message.author.send('Reminder! \n' + message.content[10:-3])

    if message.content[-1] == 'm':
        time.sleep(int(message.content[-2])*60)
        await message.author.send('Reminder! \n' + message.content[10:-3])



client.run(TOKEN)
```

I know I can clean up the `if` statements, so dont worry about that.

Comment: You can either utilize multithreading, or coroutines (this is the way). Discord.py already uses them, so if you read a little on it, you can set events and accept commands in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`.

```py
import asyncio

[...]

if message.content[-1] == 'h':
    asyncio.sleep(3600 * int(message.content[-2]))
    await message.author.send('Reminder! \n' + message.content[10:-3])

[...]
```